# hibernate generate query without all outer join fetch possible

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I have 5 entities :

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<B1> b1s;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<B2> b2s;
}

@Entity
public class B1 {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="c")
    private C c;
}

@Entity
public class B2 {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="c")
    private C c;
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="d", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<D> ds;
}

@Entity
public classD {

}
```

So  in short, 
A eager join two set of Entity B1 and B2, each one eager joining (implicitely) an Entity C which in turn eager join a set of Entity D.

when loading an A object, the generated query look like

```
select (...) from A a0 
left outer join B1 b1 on a0.id=b1.aid
    left outer join C c1 on b1.cid=c1.id
        left outer join D d1 on c1.id=d1.cid
left outer join B2 b2 on a0.id=b2.aid
    left outer join C c2 on b2.cid=c2.id
where a0.id=?
```

The problem is that the Set of Entity D wich are linked to c2 (C Entity loaded via B2 Entity) are not loaded in the same query, resulting in N subsequent queries for each c2 object.

I would expect Hibernate to generate another left outer join for these objects in the first query, as it already does for the first occurence of D.

I am missing something ? I use hibernate 3.6 on an Oracle DB, is it an known issue ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this seems to be a bug or an incomplete feature. I was able to reproduce it in a simpler scenario as well:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn
    private Set<B> bs1;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn
    private Set<B> bs2;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn
    private Set<C> cs;
}

@Entity
public class C {

}
```

When loading `A` by id, the following joins are generated:

```
from
    A a0_ 
left outer join
    B bs1x1_ 
        on a0_.id=bs1x1_.bs1_id 
left outer join
    C cs2_ 
        on bs1x1_.id=cs2_.cs_id 
left outer join
    B bs2x3_ 
        on a0_.id=bs2x3_.bs2_id
```

So, if you really want to fetch everything in one query, you'll have to do it with HQL:

```
select a from A a 
left join fetch a.b1s b1 
left join fetch b1.c c1 
left join fetch c1.ds 
left join fetch a.b2s b2 
left join fetch b2.c c2 
left join fetch c2.ds 
where a.id = ?
```

However, I assume that the collections being joined are really small. Because these kinds of joins produce ***full*** Cartesian product and are considered a very bad anti-pattern.

Suppose that each of the collections contains only 100 rows (`A` has 100 `b1s` and 100 `b2s`, and each of `b1s` and `b2s` has a `C` which has 100 `ds`). Then you will get and read a result set containing 100 million rows!

But with lazy collections and batch fetching for example, you would read a total of about 400 rows in a few queries, which is much faster than reading 100 million rows in one query.

Comment: The number of row returned by querying one A is rather small. My problem is that A is batch fetched so I can't use HQL for loading it nor can I query A and its sub Entity in the original HQL query because it would return too many (large) rows